# how to get user timeline using twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter4j

Below is my code. my question is how to get the user timeline of another account? (say a public account like att). I have my consumer key, secret, access token, access secret, which are registered under my twitter account. Please help me. Thank you very much.

```
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Yusuke Yamamoto - yusuke at mac.com
 * @since Twitter4J 2.1.7
 */
public class GetUserTimeline {
    /**
     * Usage: java twitter4j.examples.timeline.GetUserTimeline
     *
     * @param args String[]
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // gets Twitter instance with default credentials
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        try {
            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
              .setOAuthConsumerKey("***")
              .setOAuthConsumerSecret("***")
              .setOAuthAccessToken("***")
              .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("***");
            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            Twitter twitter1 = tf.getInstance();
            List<Status> statuses;
            String user;
            if (args.length == 1) {
                user = args[0];
                statuses = twitter1.getUserTimeline("ATT");
            } else {
                user = twitter1.verifyCredentials().getScreenName();
                statuses = twitter1.getUserTimeline();
            }
            System.out.println("Showing @" + user + "'s user timeline.");
            for (Status status : statuses) {
                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
            }
        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to get timeline: " + te.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking `GetUserTimeline` and are you getting any errors/output?

Comment: Your code seems correct. Are you getting any error??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that if you reverted your change of:

```
statuses = twitter1.getUserTimeline("ATT");
```

to:

```
statuses = twitter1.getUserTimeline(user);
```

and invoked `GetUserTimeline` with `ATT` as a command line argument it should work.

It looks like the twitter4j examples come with [utility scripts](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/tree/master/twitter4j-examples/bin/timeline) to execute them, so it seems  you should be able to just run:

```
$ getUserTimeline.sh ATT
```